# Display images from folder and delete images

Tags: php, html

I have this script from http://lampload.com/component/option,com_jdownloads/Itemid,382/cid,69/task,view.download/
(I am not using a database) I can upload images fine, I can view files, but I want to delete them.
When I press the delete button, nothing happens

http://www.jayg.co.uk/gallery6/upload_gallery.php

```
<?php
$dir = dirname(__FILENAME__)."/images/gallery" ;
$files1 = scandir($dir);
foreach($files1 as $file){
if(strlen($file) >=3){
$foil = strstr($file, 'jpg'); // As of PHP 5.3.0
$foil = $file;
$pos = strpos($file, 'css');
if ($foil==true){
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="filenames[]" value="'.$foil.'" />';
echo "<img width='130' height='38' src='images/gallery/$file' /><br/>"; // for live host
//echo "<img width='130' height='38' src='/ABOOK/SORTING/gallery-dynamic/images/gallery/      $file' /><br/>";
}
}
}?>
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit2" value="Delete">
</form>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Where's the code which processes delete button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waw!, the way you are going about it is wrong. For simplicity why don't you implement database
in the codings. Anyway based on your request, I have developed this code along with css file. it has been tested and its working now. Please rate my response and give me a shout if you need futher assistance. .... Sectona

```
index.php
<?php
extract($_REQUEST);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>

<style>



#box{ width:200px; height:auto; border:solid #999 10px; padding:10px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:100px; background-color:#FFF;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #666;box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #666; color:#66F;}

.link{padding:5px; text-decoration:none; background-color:#333; color:#FFF}

</style>

</head>

<body>


<div id="box">


<img src="images/3.jpg" />

<p></p>

<a href="delete.php?del=1" class="link">Delete</a>

</div>


</body>
</html>



delete.php

<?php
extract($_REQUEST);


unlink("images/3.jpg");

// Redirect to a page that prints image deleted successfully

header("Location:success_delete.php");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sectona, I have tried the code, but doesn't work, I tried adding the code to my index.php and upload.php, didn't work :-( any ideas? I noticed you have unlink("images/3.jpg"); my location is different, would that code only delete 3.jpg? I need to be able to delete any image, thanks for looking :-)

Comment: this my exemplary codes works 100%. For testing purpose, All you have to do create a folder called Image and copy images into it eg 3.jpg,sectona.gif, jay.png etc. Any image you wants to delete, just call up the image name from folder and it will be okay. However, if you want to be able to delete any images then you have store all the images in a folder and their names along with their unique ID in the database. Any image you wants to delete can now be possible by using its ID Flag from the database. Without database assistance, forget about it.

Comment: If you need sound examplification with mysql database interaction, i can help you though i know its not going to be easy at least it will take more of my time. Secondly whenever you are being given an example, run it that way and then use the knowledge derived as programmer to structure your own code. Until then you will be okay